# Some website images not displaying properly on iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, mobile-safari

I've developed a responsive website, and just when I thought it was perfect and ready to launch, I found out that the images on the homepage are not displaying properly on iPhones (I developed the site while testing on an Android, so I was none the wiser about iPhone oddities until now).  The images should be fitting into the width of the screen (I've set max-width: 100%; on them), but instead they are stretched and pixelated way beyond their actual resolution.

Curiously, images on any other page of the site display just fine.  I thought the issue was rooted in the fact that the images on the homepage are actually set via a CSS background property, while images everywhere else are set in `<img>` tags in the HTML.  So I commented out the "background" declarations in the CSS file and instead used `<img>` tags on the homepage, just like everywhere else.  When I did that to the very first image, it displayed great.  However, as soon as I switched the rest of the images to HTML, they all reverted back to the ugly that was present before.

My boss (who has access to an iPhone) sent me this video (apologies for it being out of focus, but you get the idea): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vFJVZiBc3Q

The first four images he scrolls past ought to all fit above the fold, and you're only seeing the left ~1/10th of the actual image, that's how far it's stretched out.

I'm out of ideas here.  Is there anything special I need to do for iPhones?  With the `<img>` tag, these photos should be in the same format that the rest of the working images are in.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: and your code is.....

Comment: It's all about the code! There are various things to check, like viewport meta element etc. It's like getting a doctor's diagnosis. You wouldn't just send him a video. :-)

Comment: I did play around with the viewport meta element.  Currently it's just `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`, but adding max-scale=1.0 didn't fix anything.  It's a Wordpress site but I've only been playing around with the HTML/CSS files, and as far as I can tell there's no difference between how I'm declaring an `<img>` in the homepage and how I'm declaring them in the rest of the site's pages.  Is there any other pertinent information that I'm leaving out?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it was a me-specific issue.  Apologies for being vague above, I really had no idea what I should have been looking for when it came to iPhones.  The images in question were contained in `<div>`s in which I specified a height in vh units.  As a future reference for anyone reading this, you apparently shouldn't do that.  Changing height to a percent unit fixed the issue, and it displays great on both Android and iPhone!